# Copy one List to another List and SubList with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a list of employees, and all of them have another list nested which is called the EmployeeValuesCollection.

So my class is something like :-

```
public Employee(int employeeID, string jobTitle, int companyID, 
        List<EmployeeValues> employeeValuesCollection)
{
      EmployeeID = employeeID;
      JobTitle = jobTitle;
      CompanyID = companyID;
      EmployeeValuesCollection = employeeValuesCollection;
 }
```

Now I wish to populate this object from another object with LINQ, and so far I have :-

```
List<DataFileRow> dataFiles = dfRow.Rows;
dataFiles
     .ForEach(l => employeeList
                      .Add(new Employee(l.EmpID, l.JobTitle, l.CompID)));
```

That works however I do not know how to add the employeeValuesCollection in the statement.  Is it possible to do?

So I was thinking something like :-

```
dataFiles
     .ForEach(l => employeeList
                     .Add(new Employee(l.EmpID, l.JobTitle, l.CompID, 
                          new List<EmployeeValuesCollection> .............)));
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Well, that's not going to work. You can't assign a `List<EmployeeValuesCollection>` to a single `EmployeeValuesCollection`. What *exactly* do you wish to assign to it?

Comment: ok so basically I am getting an object, which has en employee, and then a list of variables attached to every employee.  Now I want to get these values in my class, so that I can manipulate the data I want.  The object I am getting is exactly like my object but with different property names.

Comment: how are `EmployeeValuesCollection` values expected (assuming they might be in multiples) are they part of `dataFiles` ?

Comment: yes basically 1 datafile will have 1 employee, and then a List<> of Values, however there is more details in the List<Values> that I need, so that is why I am creating my own object

Comment: What property or properties in dataFiles make up the object you want in EmployeeValuesCollection?

Comment: basically there are 3 properties that i really need, title, value and isVisible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be better to iterate through the input parameter employeeValuesCollection list inside the Employee constructor to create a local variable of type EmployeeValues and add it to the Employee class's instance list variable. If we use EmployeeValuesCollection = employeeValuesCollection;, we are actually assigning the reference. So if we modify some values of employeeValuesCollection, the same change will get reflected to EmployeeValuesCollection.

```
public Employee(int employeeID, string jobTitle, int companyID, List<EmployeeValues> employeeValuesCollection)
    {
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        JobTitle = jobTitle;
        CompanyID = companyID;

        foreach (var obj in employeeValuesCollection)
        {
            var empVal = new EmployeeValues() { Name = obj.Name};
            EmployeeValuesCollection.Add(empVal);
        }
```

And you can use the LINQ statement as

```
dataFiles.ForEach(l => employeeList.Add(new Employee(l.EmpID, l.JobTitle, l.CompID, l.EmployeeValuesCollection)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Linq projection over each row.  I'll do it in 'proper' linq:

```
employeeList = (from r in dfRow.Rows
  select new Employee(r.EmpID, r.JobTitle, r.CompID, 
   new List<EmployeeValues>(/*parameter*/))).ToList();
```

Until you specify what `EmployeeValues` actually is (and which property on `DataFileRow` they're accessed from) it's difficult to say any more.  But let's say it's just more properties, and I'll summise they are like key/value pairs (despite the name pluralisation on the type, that's a bit confusing).

I've taken the names here from your third comment on your question, and assumed that `DataFileRow` type exposes these values as an IEnumerable called `EmployeeValues`.  Based on that - you can use an inner projection.

```
employeeList = (from r in dfRow.Rows
  select new Employee(r.EmpID, r.JobTitle, r.CompID, 
   new List<EmployeeValue>((from v in r.EmployeeValues
    select new EmployeeValues(v.title, v.value, v.isVisible))).ToList());
```

Comment: thanks Andras, that should work however the EmployeeValues is not as straight forward as it looks.  I will have a word with the developer that craeted that object, but I tried your code on something else and it works.  Thanks!